# not-found.js file renders empty in Next 14

Tags: next.js

I have a `not-found.tsx` file in the `app` folder of my Next application.

```
-- /src/app/not-found.tsx --

export default function NotFound() {
    console.log("render not found")
    return <div>Not Found</div>
}
```

If I try to a navigate to an unhandled route I see the log in the console but the layout renders without contents.

```
<html id="__next_error__">
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <script>...</script>
        <script>...</script>
        ... (a bunch of next.js scripts)
    </body>
</html>
```

**What should I do to have next recognize the jsx I want to display for unhandled routes?**

Comment: everything looks fine... have you tried cleaning cache and restarting the server? you cen delete .next folder and try again. sometimes it's resolves many problem. or maybe it's only problem in dev server. try prod build using `npm run build` then `npm start`

Comment: it was an issue with my layout.tsx, for some reason I had a `div` at the top-level instead of an `html` tag